# Python Dataframe - only keep oldest records from each month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a date column. I want to only have the oldest records for each month and remove any records that came before. There will be duplicates and I want to keep them. I also need a new column with only the month and year.

Input

| Provider | date |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 01/01/2022 |
| Apple | 05/01/2022 |
| Apple | 20/01/2022 |
| Apple | 20/01/2022 |
| Apple | 05/02/2022 |
| Apple | 10/02/2022 |

Output:

| Provider | date | month_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 20/01/2022 | 01/2022 |
| Apple | 20/01/2022 | 01/2022 |
| Apple | 10/02/2022 | 02/2022 |

Comment: Since SO is not a code-writing service, where *specifically* are you stuck implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create column `month_year` with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and then compare maximal datetimes per groups by original `date` column in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.assign(month_year = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y'))

df = df[df.groupby(['Provider', 'month_year'])['date'].transform('max').eq(df['date'])]
print (df)
  Provider       date month_year
2    Apple 2022-01-20    01/2022
3    Apple 2022-01-20    01/2022
5    Apple 2022-02-10    02/2022
```